# Class Attributes (?) in ASP.NET Web Form Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have created a custom BoundField class in C#. I have added ASP.NET validators to the TextBox and exposed the TextBox OnTextChanged event in Edit and Insert modes. I am experiencing an annoyance with the validators though.

I have exposed the validators publicly like in this example:

```
private RequiredFieldValidator _requiredFieldValidator;
public RequiredFieldValidator RequiredFieldValidator
{
    get { return _requiredFieldValidator ?? (_requiredFieldValidator = new RequiredFieldValidator()); }
}
```

I have used this approach to avoid having to set up countless custom public properties in the control itself. I can now do this...

```
<cc1:BoundFieldWithTextChangedEvent DataField="size2" HeaderText="Width" SortExpression="size2" ItemStyle-CssClass="numeric" OnTextChanged="size2_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
            RequiredFieldValidator-Text="!"
            RequiredFieldValidator-Display="Dynamic" />
```

This code compiles fine and the validations work properly on the page; but I am seeing squiggles under the "RequiredFieldValidator-Text" and "RequiredFieldValidator-Display" attributes in Visual Studio 2013. The first warning is:

> Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'RequiredFieldValidator-Text' is not a
>   valid attribute of element 'BoundFieldWithTextChangedEvent'.

The other warnings are for the rest of the "RequiredFieldValidator-" attributes.

What do I need to do my custom control code to make these attributes behave properly with Visual Studio 2013?

**EDIT:** Thanks to Alex Lebedev's help below, my problem has been solved.

I needed to do two things:

1. Add `[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]` above my public validator properties in my custom control.
2. Reference the validators as inner elements of my custom control on the web form page.

```html
<cc1:BoundFieldWithTextChangedEvent DataField="size2" HeaderText="Width" SortExpression="size2" ItemStyle-CssClass="numeric" OnTextChanged="size2_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ValidationGroup="UpdateItem">
    <RequiredFieldValidator Text="!" ErrorMessage="You must specify a width." Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" EnableClientScript="true"></RequiredFieldValidator>
    <CompareValidator Text="*" ErrorMessage="Width must be greater than zero." Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" Type="Double" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" EnableClientScript="true"></CompareValidator>
</cc1:BoundFieldWithTextChangedEvent>
```

Comment: Don't have VS at hand to try, but i suspect that something like `RequiredFieldValidator$Text` may work

Comment: Andrei, thank you for the suggestion; but if I change `RequiredFieldValidator-Text` to `RequiredFieldValidator$Text`, I receive an "unexpected token" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cc1:BoundFieldWithTextChangedEvent DataField="size2" HeaderText="Width" SortExpression="size2" ItemStyle-CssClass="numeric" OnTextChanged="size2_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
            RequiredFieldValidator-Text="!"
            RequiredFieldValidator-Display="Dynamic" />
```

Replace it with:

```
<cc1:BoundFieldWithTextChangedEvent DataField="size2" HeaderText="Width" SortExpression="size2" ItemStyle-CssClass="numeric" OnTextChanged="size2_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <RequiredFieldValidator Text="!" Display="Dynamic"/>
</cc1:BoundFieldWithTextChangedEvent>
```

Comment: Oh! We're getting CLOSER! Now I see... `Validation (XHTML5): Element 'requiredfieldvalidator' is not supported.`

Comment: FIXED! Added `[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]` above my `RequiredFieldValidator` property.  Thank you!